# Given a collection of vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, which inner products $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$ are needed to uniquely determine all inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, spherical-geometry

Given a collection of vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, which inner products $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$ need to be known to uniquely determine all inner products? I'll begin with the specific case I am interested and then ask a more general question.

Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_4$ are a collection of (unknown) unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle,\langle x_2,x_3\rangle,\langle x_3,x_4\rangle,\langle x_4,x_1\rangle$ is the value of $\langle x_1,x_3\rangle$ uniquely determined? I'm essentially positive they are with some algebra, linear algebra, and a proof by image, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to solve this and/or results that yield a more straightforward way to show this.

The above can be considered like a square graph, with edges between two vectors indicating a known inner product. Given the same situation, with different dimension and/or different number of vectors, can we determine the uniqueness of all inner products given the graph structure?

Edit: I'm wondering if this can be nicely formalized as a graph rigidity problem... I'm also interested in the case where the norm of each $x_i$ is unknown, other than being nonzero.

Comment: I really don't think this is correct. These values don't change with transform by G in O(2). 

From this we can just assume x_1= [1,0], and x_2,1 x_4,1 are also determined then. We also know (x_2,2)^2 by (x_2,2)^2 = 1 -(x_2,1)^2, and likewise for x_4,2^2. Because its the _general_ orthogonal group we can further assume x_2,2 is positive. Two degrees of freedom x_3 and one sign x_4,2 are all that are unknown. We have 2 equations involving x_3 from the inner products, and one equation since its norm is known. So we really have 2 unknown reals and 1 unknown sign. It gets messy from here.

Comment: ah, I thought about 3d sphere

Comment: on the plane the answer is still negative: take 4 points such that $x_1x_4$ is a diameter of the unit circle and replace $x_1$ to a point symmetric to $x_1$ with respect this diameter

Comment: If I understand correctly, $x_1=-x_4$? Then isn't $\left<x_1,x_3\right> = -\left<x_3,x_4\right>$ which is known..

Comment: Sorry, $x_2=-x_4$. In complex coordinates, $x_4=1,x_2=-1$, $x_3$ is arbitrary and $x_1$ may be replace to $\bar{x}_1$ without changing the four given scalar products

Comment: The uniqueness of the inner products is all I am interested in not in vectors themselves.

Comment: If you restrict to unit vectors, then your setting is equivalent to what people study in rigidity theory as *(global) rigidity of spherical frameworks*. Another keyword to look up in this context is "matrix completion".

Comment: @M.Winter this looks like a very good starting point, thanks!

Comment: Another way to frame this question, at least for the standard inner product: if we take $X$ to be a matrix whose columns are $x_1,\dots,x_k$, then what you have is knowledge of some of the entries of the (positive semidefinite) matrix $X^TX$.  For your case, we have
$$
X^TX = \pmatrix{1 & \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle & ? & \langle x_1, x_4 \rangle\\
\langle x_2, x_1 \rangle & 1 & \langle x_2, x_3 \rangle & ?\\
?&\langle x_3,x_2 \rangle & 1 & \langle x_3,x_4 \rangle\\
\langle x_4,x_1 \rangle & ? & \langle x_4, x_3 \rangle & 1}.
$$

Comment: The possible ways of assigning the remaining inner products is equivalent to the possible ways of filling in the entries of $X^TX$ that maintain the positive semidefiniteness property. In other words, this is a positive semidefinite matrix completion problem.

Comment: @BenGrossmann this also looks good thank you. I guess I can attempt to solve this via a constrained optimization problem.

Comment: in my example the inner product of $x_1$ and $x_3$ also changes

Comment: Okay I get it now, thanks. Seems like the diameter, thing is necessary for this counterexample to work…